# How to add a set of directory libraries to C++ and Code Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, point-cloud-library

I have recently started programming C++ and can't figure out how one goes about adding libraries. I am using Code Blocks by the way.

I have downloaded the PCL (Point Cloud Library) repository from GitHub. Now I would like to use some of these files in my own code.

I have tried a simple example that starts by importing this:

```
#include <pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
```

Here I get the classic fatal error for no such file or directory. If I change it to the following it works: (To my understanding, this is because I have placed the library in the same directory as my code. This is the only way I have had any success so far)

```
#include "pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h"
```

The problem now is that in this included header file, other files are included from the same library, which gives the same error.

I am planning on using many of the files in this library. Changing all of them seems ineffective and time consuming. Is there another way I can add all of these files to include them in an easier way?

Here is a link to the repository if it helps to see the file structure or anything, I guess.
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl

On the website, they had this tutorial. I could not get this working: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/using_pcl_pcl_config.html#using-pcl-pcl-config

Comment: Add an include path to the compiler command line. I'm not sure how to do this in code::blocks, but in the command line it's `-I<path to library include folder>`. This also allows you to place your libraries anywhere on your system, not embedded in a project folder. Aids in reuse.

Comment: Second post here looks like pretty good instructions: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9366.0